# Storing many small documents without redundant fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is a subset of the classic many small vs. few large documents problem in mongoDB. Right now I have a large mongodb document that looks like this:

```
//Collection: Everything
{
    _id: "1",
    date: Date(...),
    target: "192.168.0.7"
    tests: [
        {
            name: "Speed Test",
            components: [
                {
                    name: "Upload Test"
                    results: [ { "upload_speed_Mbps" : 5 }, ... ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Download Test"
                    results: [ ... ]
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The problem is that it is very difficult to take advantage of mongoDB's aggregation features with a document structure like this because if I want, say, an array of all upload speeds recorded on a given target between two dates, the upload speed statistic is nested 3 arrays deep and mongo doesn't know how to find it unless I do a triple unwind (which I believe is a costly operation).

Therefore, it seems better/faster for mongoDB to have collections of smaller documents like such:

```
//Collection: Suites
{
    _id: "1",
    date: Date(...),
    target_ip: "192.168.0.7"
    tests: [
        "1a",
        "2a",
        "3a",
        ...
    ]
}

//Collection: Tests
{
    _id: "1a",
    name: "Speed Test",
    components: [
        "1b",
        "2b",
        "3b",
        ...
    ]
}

//Collection: Components
{
    _id: "1b",
    name: "Upload Test",
    results: [
        "1c",
        "2c",
        "3c",
        ...
    ]
}

//Collection: Results
{
    _id: "1c",
    name: "upload_speed_Mbps",
    value: 5
}
```

That way I can aggregate across Results documents directly. Now my question is, if I want to quickly aggregate a collection of upload speeds that occurred on a given target between two dates, is my only option to include the `date` and `target` fields inside every document in the `Results` collection? This seems redundant when the information is already accessible at the top level document.

Am I correct in assuming I can either:

1. Have redundant information in my sub documents to gain fast aggregation

or

2. Don't have redundant information in my sub documents but lose fast aggregation due to costly unwind operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operations are generally costly when you are performing the operation on large collections of documents which themselves have large arrays or large nested arrays.

In the case for this query, you can use your original document structure and simply [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) for the `target` and `date` range right at the beginning. That limits the size of the data being handled with the `$unwind`. You can also [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to further limit the amount of data that will be handled by the aggregation. This should reduce the cost of the query considerably.

If you still prefer to separate all the components out how you have outlined, then yes you will need to include the information you wish to query on in the documents that are being queried.